# Sitecore JSS GraphQL Search - Unknown argument where on field search of type Query

Tags: graphql

I am trying to execute one search query from graph ql ui but I am getting the following error.

```
Unknown argument \"where\" on field \"search\" of type \"Query\"."
```

I am using the default out of the box end point **/sitecore/api/graph/items/master**
Also the search schema is already there in the Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.config file.
In Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Master.config file the scema provider is mapped .

```
<schema hint="list:AddSchemaProvider">
                            <!-- defaults are defined in Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.config -->
                            <content ref="/sitecore/api/GraphQL/defaults/content/schemaProviders/systemContent" param1="master" />                          
                        </schema>
```

So to me everything looks fine but still I am getting this error.

[image]

```
query DictionarySearch(
    $rootItemId: String!
    $language: String!
    $templates: String!
    $pageSize: Int = 10
    $after: String
  ) {
    search(
      where: {
        AND: [
          { name: "_path", value: $rootItemId, operator: CONTAINS }
          { name: "_language", value: $language }
          { name: "_templates", value: $templates, operator: CONTAINS }
        ]
      }
      first: $pageSize
      after: $after
    ) {
      total
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNext
      }
      results {
        key: field(name: "Key") {
          value
        }
        phrase: field(name: "Phrase") {
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. Look at this example from the Sitecore docs

```
query {
  pageOne: search(
     where: {
       AND: [
         {
           name: "_path"
           value: "54C8E9B5-0B2C-5363-8FA6-D32A3A302F51"
           operator: CONTAINS
         }
         {
           AND: [
             {
               name: "_path"
               value: "0C6F4AAF-DD7E-5FAF-B9B0-61070D496055"
               operator: NCONTAINS
             }
             {
               name: "_path"
               value: "AB99BA2B-B606-51E3-BAD9-FD8358DE1333"
               operator: NCONTAINS
             }
           ]
         }
       ]
     }
     # defaults to 10
     first: 10
   ) {
     total
     pageInfo {
       endCursor
       hasNext
     }
     results {
       url {
         path
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

In your code it's seeing the 'search' name as a field not a command.

Comment: OK I will check on this . But the query I am using is just out of the box react jss app. I did not write it . I have updated the query above. The above query also gives me the same error.

Comment: Simple search query is working but the above mention query is not working. not sure If I need to add any specific confif changes

Answer (score 0):

It seems like **/sitecore/api/graph/items/master** endpoint does not support the above search query parameters. So when I switched to **/sitecore/api/graph/edge?sc_apikey={APIKEY}** it starts working.